# Python.exe getting hanged while running script having pandas and list implementation

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have developed a script to process CSV file & generate another result file. Script is running successfully with limited test data but when i executed it with actual data file having 25 million rows in 15 columns then same script is getting hanged and closes abruptly. See attached error screen shot.

So, is there any maximum limit i can read using pandas from CSV file OR maximum limit on storing records in list..?

Kindly share your thoughts to optimize below script.

[[image: Error Screen Shot]]

Below is script.

```
import csv
import operator
import pandas as pd
import time

print time.strftime('Script Start Time : ' + "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
sourceFile = raw_input('Enter file name along with path : ')
searchParam1 = raw_input('Enter first column name containing MSISDN : ').lower()
searchParam2 = raw_input('Enter second column name containing DATE-TIME : ').lower()
searchParam3 = raw_input('Enter file seperator (,/#/|/:/;) : ')

df = pd.read_csv(sourceFile, sep=searchParam3)
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
df = df.rename(columns={searchParam1 : 'msisdn', searchParam2 : 'datetime'})

destFileWritter = csv.writer(open(sourceFile + ' - ProcessedFile.csv','wb'))
destFileWritter.writerow(df.keys().tolist())
sortedcsvList = df.sort_values(['msisdn','datetime']).values.tolist()

rows = [row for row in sortedcsvList]
col_1 = [row[df.columns.get_loc('msisdn')] for row in rows]
col_2 = [row[df.columns.get_loc('datetime')] for row in rows]

for i in range(0,len(col_1)-1):
    if col_1[i] == col_1[i+1]:
        #print('Inside If...')
        continue
    else:
        for row in rows:
            if col_1[i] in row:
                if col_2[i] in row:
                    #print('Inside else...')
                    destFileWritter.writerow(row)
destFileWritter.writerow(rows[len(rows)-1])
print('Processing Completed, Kindly Check Response File On Same Location.')
print time.strftime('Script End Time : ' + "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
raw_input('Press Enter to Exit...')[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

***Updated Script:***

```
import csv
import operator
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys

print time.strftime('Script Start Time : ' + "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
sourceFile = raw_input('Enter file name along with path : ')
searchParam1 = raw_input('Enter first column name containing MSISDN : ').lower()
searchParam2 = raw_input('Enter second column name containing DATE-TIME : ').lower()
searchParam3 = raw_input('Enter file seperator (,/#/|/:/;) : ')

def csvSortingFunc(sourceFile, searchParam1, searchParam2, searchParam3):
    CHUNKSIZE = 10000
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(sourceFile, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE, sep=searchParam3):
        df = chunk
        #df = pd.read_csv(sourceFile, sep=searchParam3)
        df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
        df = df.rename(columns={searchParam1 : 'msisdn', searchParam2 : 'datetime'})
        """destFileWritter = csv.writer(open(sourceFile + ' - ProcessedFile.csv','wb'))
        destFileWritter.writerow(df.keys().tolist()) """
        resultList = []
        resultList.append(df.keys().tolist())
        sortedcsvList = df.sort_values(['msisdn','datetime']).values.tolist()
        rows = [row for row in sortedcsvList]
        col_1 = [row[df.columns.get_loc('msisdn')] for row in rows]
        col_2 = [row[df.columns.get_loc('datetime')] for row in rows]
        for i in range(0,len(col_1)-1):
            if col_1[i] == col_1[i+1]:
                #print('Inside If...')
                continue
            else:
                for row in rows:
                    if col_1[i] in row:
                        if col_2[i] in row:
                            #print('Inside else...')
                            #destFileWritter.writerow(row)
                            resultList.append(row)
        #destFileWritter.writerow(rows[len(rows)-1])
    resultList.append(rows[len(rows)-1])
    writedf = pd.DataFrame(resultList)
    writedf.to_csv(sourceFile + ' - ProcessedFile.csv', header=False, index=False)
    #print('Processing Completed, Kindly Check Response File On Same Location.')


csvSortingFunc(sourceFile, searchParam1, searchParam2, searchParam3)
print('Processing Completed, Kindly Check Response File On Same Location.')
print time.strftime('Script End Time : ' + "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
raw_input('Press Enter to Exit...')
```

Comment: maybe some memory limits? did you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can easily aggregate the results you should most definitely consider using parameter *chunksize* in *pd.read_csv*. It allows you to read large *.csv* file in chunks of lets say 100000 records.

```
chunksize = 10000
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunk_size):
    df = chunk
    #your code
```

Afterwards you should append results from each computation into a final one.
Hope it helps, I've used this approach while working with files exceeding few millions lines.

Continued:

```
    i = 0
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(sourceFile, chunksize=10):
        print('chunk_no', i)
        i+=1
```

May you run these few lines? Does it print out some numbers?

Comment: Thanks, this solution has help to get rid of error i mentioned above. I will have to iterate through whole file and process it. Thanks for support.

Comment: I have implemented above suggested way in my code but i found that file is iterating only once through CHUNKSIZE and complete file isn't processing... Can you help me how can i process whole file chunk-by-chunk...?

Comment: Because if you did, then before I edited it there was missing indentation of '#your code' that 's probably why it processed only the last chunk of the file, sorry for this error.

Comment: Hi, no i didn't copied as it is but took your code as a reference. See updated script which uses CHUNKSIZE under "Updated Script" tag in main question. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Edited my response, try to run that code and tell me what you get